# How to check if the item is not initialized?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, initialization, nullreferenceexception

I can't find any where that solve this problem.
I wrote a unit test to test this method

```
    public double CalculateTotalWeight()
    {
        double result = 0;
        if (Store?.TypeOfRacquet.Any())
        {
            result = Store.TypeOfRacquet.Sum(m => m.Weight);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The unit test failed because of `nullexceptionreference` object is not initialized on the Weight property.
How do i check if there's any Weight property, or the weight property is initialized?

I have tried numerous ways

```
if (Store?.TypeOfRacquet.Any())
if (Store?.TypeOfRacquet.Where(m => m.Weight != null)
if (Store?.TypeOfRacquet.First().Weight != null)
```

EDIT

here's my Weight property inside TypeOfRacquet

```
public int Weight
    {
        get { return Get<int>(); }
        set { Set(value); }
    }
```

my unit test

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CalculateTotalt_Without_Weight_Test()
    {
        var entity = new Store
        {
            TypeOfRacquet = new TypeOfRacquet
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid()
            }
        };

        var result = entity.CalculateTotalWeight();

        Assert.AreEqual(0, result);
    }
```

when debugged, i get the System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of object

Comment: Are you sure it's the weight property? a `double` can't be `null`

Comment: @RufusL it said it is not initialized

Comment: `double` is a struct, and structs are always initialized to their default value. What is the exact exception message, and which line is throwing it?

Comment: What about `TypeOfRacquet`? Can that be `null`?

Comment: This shouldnt compile for another reason, `Store?.TypeOfRacquet.Any()` is a `bool?` not a `bool`, you can't use it in the `if`. Is that really your code? You had to use `if(Store?.TypeOfRacquet.Any()==true){}`

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes it passed debugged

Comment: @RufusL System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Dnguy025  Slow down.  Read all the words people are posting and answer all the questions.  We cant see anything related to weight and your tags indicate a different exception than NRE.

Comment: I have even better question.. aren't you doing unit testing to improve your code? So, instead of asking, "why", debug, improve and see if unit test runs

Comment: Deleted my answer, as per your comment in it suggested that `Weight` is a non-nullable property (as you could not apply the Null-Coalescing operator to it), and @KennethK. highlighted that Sum() ignores null values, which invalidates my previous answer. This all points out that the null-exception is really fired by something other than the `Weight` property.

Comment: @RufusL, i see. yep, you're right.

Comment: You still haven't provided enough information. Your getters and setters for `Weight` are calling other methods that we don't have the definitions for, and the `CaculateTotalWeight` is referring to a `Store` object whose definition/initialization we cannot see, and you haven't told us **which line of code is throwing the exception**. Realize that we will copy/paste your code into visual studio, and run it (if we don't see the error on our own), so please provide enough information to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for all the help, this is what i did that works for me

```
if (Store != null)
{
    foreach (var racquet in Store.TypeOfRacquet)
    {
        result += racquet.Weight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the problem is that your `TypeOfRacquet` is null. You should check for that as well, in your `if` condition before you try to call the `Any` method:

```
double result = 0;
if (Store?.TypeOfRacquet != null && Store.TypeOfRacquet.Any())
{
    result = Store.TypeOfRacquet.Sum(m => m.Weight);
}
return result;
```

Or, more simply:

```
return Store?.TypeOfRacquet?.Sum(m => m.Weight) ?? 0;
```

Comment: thanks I have tried that, but consider the scenario when TypeOfRacquet is not null because there's more property inside TypeOfRAcquet then just Weight

Comment: Regardless of the other properties belonging to `TypeOfRacquet`, it's either `null` or it's not. Since we aren't accessing any other properties that might be `null` (and `Weight` is an `int`, which can't be `null`), there should be no problem. If you've tried this and are getting an exception, then please post the exact exception and the exact line which is throwing it. Or better yet, use your debugger and step through the code, so you can examine the values at runtime.

Comment: the sum would cause error if i don't initialized a Weight inside my unit test

Comment: Then please include a minimal example that we can copy/paste to repro the problem. All the information you've given so far does not correlate with the errors you say you're getting. If `Weight` is an `int` (which you said it was based on your comment to the deleted question) then it's automatically initialized and that is **not** the problem. As it stands, you've not given us enough to work with. Please include a minimal class definition for `Store` (i.e. show the `TypeOfRacquet` definition and the class that has a `Weight` property) that we can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Also, `if (Store?.TypeOfRacquet.Any())` shouldn't compile. When you add the `?` in there, the result of `Any()` becomes a `System.Nullable<bool>`, so you'd have to explicitly include something like `== true` or `?? false` after `Any()`, or write it like `if ((Store?.TypeOfRacquet.Any()).GetValueOrDefault())`